# Logged in value issue between PHP scripts

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am reading a lot regarding the best practice to monitor when a user is logged in or not.

Currently i am trying to use a variable in a session like below:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

//I set that variable to false
$_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] = FALSE;

{follows some code that checks the username and the password provided by the user 
in an HTML form with POST request against the records of the database. If a match is
found then it allows the user to proceed with the loggin}

if($statement->rowCount() = 1) //
{
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] = TRUE;
header('Location: mainpage.php');
}
else
{
echo "wrong username or password";
}

?>
```

**mainpage.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(($_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] == TRUE) && isset($_SESSION['LOGGED_IN']))
{
echo "You are now logged in!";
}
else
{
echo "You are not logged in. Please retry.";
}

?>
```

The problem is that when i use a correct pair of credentials SOMETIMES i log in getting the "You are now logged in!" message, and sometimes using the same credentials i get the "You are not logged in. Please retry.".

I've added that message in the else statement on purpose. Normally there i will insert a redirection to the login page.

I am getting confused because this is an error that i shouldn't have. In the login.php script i am making sure that in order to redirect to the mainpage.php the $_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] = TRUE. So that value should be transferred to the mainpage.php as TRUE and not FALSE.

What am i missing here?

And a general question regarding loggin:
Is it better to keep the login value (TRUE or FALSE) in a session or use a table in MySQL with a flag indicating when a user is logged in or not?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, it should be `isset($_SESSION['LOGGED_IN']) && $_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] == TRUE`, not the other way.

Comment: `if($statement->rowCount() = 1)` does not make sense.  You want `==`.

Comment: @rafal - i saw it before posting and i didnt change it on purpose. Does it affect the result? Is there a difference between the one you wrote and mine?

Comment: @animism- in my code i have it with ==

Comment: Yes. If there's no 'LOGGED_IN' key, you will get a notice. If you check isset() first and it returns `false`, the `$_SESSION['LOGGED_IN']` will never run.

Comment: Or put another way, `if` conditions evaluate left to right.  Order matters.